# GetLocalizedLabel not working under Grouped Products

Tags: magento2, attributes, grouped-products, labels

I'm trying to extract 3 attributes for every associated product under a grouped product page.

I use a multistore Italian-English but if I use

```
 $stato_label= $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('stato')->getFrontend()->getLocalizedLabel($_item);
 $stato_value= $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('stato')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
```

Just the attributes value has been translated.
The label is still is not using the translation

[image: grouped]

I have already translated the labels on the backend

How can I get the translated image?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The correct way to get the label is

```
getResource()->getAttribute('attr')->getStoreLabel();
```